# Cannot Mount SD card after it is removed without Umount

Tags: linux, udev, yocto

Good afternoon,

I have a project where the SD card may become momentarily disconnected due to a weak contact on the SD Detect pin. I want to be able to check if it has been unmounted and remount it in software.

My SD card partition is `/dev/mmcblk1p1`
It is originally mounted automatically when Linux boots up

If I execute a `umount /mnt/storage` command, then remove the SD card, I can re-insert it, and perform a  `mount /dev/mmcblk1p1 /mnt/storage`  without issues

However, if I remove the SD card first, without `umount`, executing `mount /dev/mmcblk1p1 /mnt/storage`    results in

```
mounting /dev/mmcblk1p1 on /mnt/storage failed: No such device or address
```

I tried running

```
umount /mnt/storage
rmdir /mnt/storage
mkdir /mnt/storage
```

This error always comes up when the SD card is removed without unmounting

I'm using a Yocto distribution running on Imx6.

Comment: Do an `ls /dev` before and after. IIRC, even if the system sees the device after it's been reinserted, it may use a different name in `/dev` because of systemd and/or udev, etc, particularly if there is more than one device. If the 2nd `ls` has _no_ entry, the system may not have seen the reinsert. Check the system logs, `lspci`, `lsusb`, `/sys/...*` to find it

Comment: doesn't belong in a programming forum ... OT.

Answer (score 3):

If the SD card is written to by a C++ application, it can be forcefully removed, but it cannot be umount(ed) until that application closes the file descriptors. The application itself does not need to close.

This solution is for mechanical applications, where the SD card (or other flash media) may become momentary disconnected, and needs to be resumed writing to by an application:

Answer:

1. Forcefully remove the SD card
2. Detect that the SD card is disconnected

Simplest way to do this is check the SD cards' mount size

```
read file "/sys/block/mmcblk1/size" and check it's > 0
```

3. Close all file descriptors that are writing to files on the SD card.

Note that it's not necessary to close these before the card is removed. Linux is robust enough to write to a non-existing file. But this needs to be done before the SD card is umount'ed, otherwise umount will fail, and this is what was causing my problem. Umount also cannot be ran when the SD card is already re-inserted.

4. Umount the SD card

   system("umount /mnt/storage");'
5. Now re-insert the SD card
6. Detect the Card has been reinserted
7. Mount the card again

   system("mount /dev/mmcblk1p1 /mnt/storage")

Answer (score 0):

If you have udev running on your system you can let udev's mount script auto-unmount your devices if they are removed.
Therefore add something like the following in `/etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh`:

```
UMOUNT="/bin/umount"

if [ "$ACTION" = "remove" ] && [ -x "$UMOUNT" ] && [ -n "$DEVNAME" ]; then
        for mnt in `cat /proc/mounts | grep "$DEVNAME" | cut -f 2 -d " " `; do
                $UMOUNT $mnt
        done
fi
```

Furthermore you have to tell udev to run that mount script on added and removed devices. Therefore I've created `/etc/udev/rules.d/autounmount.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="remove" RUN+="/etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh"
```

This works fine for me using Yocto "Daisy" on an armv7 platform.